# Connecting to MS SQL Server using python on linux with 'Windows Credentials'

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, freetds, unixodbc

Is there any way to connect to an MS SQL Server database with python on linux using Windows Domain Credentials?

I can connect perfectly fine from my windows machine using Windows Credentials, but attempting to do the same from a linux python with pyodbs + freetds + unixodbc

```
>>import pyodbc
>>conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=servername;UID=username;PWD=password;DATABASE=dbname")
```

results in this error:

```
class 'pyodbc.Error'>: ('28000', '[28000] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login incorrect. (20014) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

I'm sure the password is written correctly, but I've tried many different combinations of username:

```
DOMAIN\username
DOMAIN\\username
```

or even

```
UID=username;DOMAIN=domain
```

to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As pointed out in one of the comments, this answer is quite stale by now. I regularly and routinely use GSSAPI to authenticate from Linux to SQL Server 2008 R2 but mostly with the EasySoft ODBC manager and the (commercial) EasySoft ODBC SQL Server driver.**

In early 2009, a colleague and I managed to connect to a SQL Server 2005 instance from Solaris 10 using GSSAPI (Kerberos credentials) using DBB::Perl over a FreeTDS build linked against a particular version of the MIT kerberos libraries. The trick was -- and this is a little bit difficult to believe but I have verified it by looking through the FreeTDS source code -- to specify a *zero-length* user_name. If the length of the user_name string is 0 then the FreeTDS code will attempt to use GSSAPI (if that support has been compiled in). I have not been able to do this via Python and pyodbc as I could not figure out a way of getting ODBC to pass down a zero-length user_name.

Here in the perl code .. there are multiple opportunities for breakage wrt configuration files such as .freetds.conf etc. I seem to recall that the principal had to be in uppercase but my notes seem to be in disagreement with that.

```
$serverprincipal = 'MSSQLSvc/foo.bar.yourdomain.com:1433@YOURDOMAIN.COM';
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Sybase:server=THESERVERNAME;kerberos=$serverprincipal", '', '');
```

You will have to know how to use the setspn utility in order to get the SQL Server server to use the appropriate security principal name.

I do not have any knowledge of the kerberos side of things because our environment was set up by an out and out Kerberos guru and has fancy stuff like mutual trust set up between the AD domain that the SQL Server is running in and the Kerberos domain that my client was running in.

There is some code http://code.google.com/p/libsqljdbc-auth/ which does GSSAPI authentication from Linux to SQL Server but it is Java only. The author (who seems to know his stuff) also has contributed a similar patch to the jTDS project which works with more recent versions of Java that have GSSAPI built in.

So the pieces are all there, it is just a big tangled mess trying to get them all to work together. I found the pyodbc to unixODBC to FreeTDS odbc to TDS integration pretty hard to trace/debug. The perl stuff because it was a pretty thin wrapper on top to CT-Lib was much easier to get going.

Comment: It's an epic tale to be sure but it's now too misleading for the current state of affairs to be both the highest and accepted answer. Let me know if you edit in a disclaimer and I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 5):

As of at least March 2013, this seems to work out of the box with FreeTDS. I specified the [TDS protocol version](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm) for good measure--not sure if that makes the difference:

```
connStr = "DRIVER={{FreeTDS}};SERVER={0};PORT=1433;TDS_Version=7.2;UID={1}\\{2};PWD={3}".format(hostname, active_directory_domain, username, password)
```

Integrated authentication also appears to be supported in Microsoft's official driver for linux: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568450.aspx . I'm not sure how many Linux distributions it actually works on or how much of the source is available. They explicitly mention RHEL 5 and 6 and some dependencies on the [download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160).

Comment: This worked for me.  The key was prepending the ad domain to the username.

Comment: Adding `TDS_Version=7.2;` allowed domain based sql server login from a linux based os to a sql server instance running on windows.

Comment: I had to replace `FreeTDS` with `/usr/local/anaconda/lib/libtdsodbc.so`, but otherwise this worked.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done it in a while, but I remember the whole unixodbc + FreeTDS + pyodbc thing being a little tricky.  However, it can be done, and once setup it's not that hard.

This website provides very good instructions:
[http://www.pauldeden.com/2008/12/how-to-setup-pyodbc-to-connect-to-mssql.html (archived copy on Web Archive)](http://web.archive.org/web/20150214152131/http://www.pauldeden.com/2008/12/how-to-setup-pyodbc-to-connect-to-mssql.html)

Also, in my experience pyodbc had issues compiling/running on 64 bit Linux machines.  Because of that we eventually used ceODBC.  ceODBC isn't quite as stable as pyodbc (encountered more unexpected bugs than in pyodbc when running in python prorgram), but it is very easy to get up and running on Linux 64 bit.

Comment: I've already used that website for instructions, it doesn't help with Windows Credentials login, although it provides a good introduction for setting the whole system up.

Comment: Downvote because this answer doesn't explicitly address Integrated Authentication/"Windows Credentials" per the question.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit too late to help you out - but I encountered the same issue. At the time of writing, the latest version of pyodbc allows me to login with windows credentials. Just leave the UID field blank in your connection string like so:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myserverinstance;DATABASE=mydatabase;UID=;PWD=mypassword')
```

Now this is using your existing windows credentials when you're logged on... not sure how to specify any arb windows domain credentials...

Comment: @tponthieux: Yes, the code (at least in my answer) works on Linux.

Comment: @anbanm, if you are specifying password in connection string, how is this integrated authentication?

Comment: @Chetan  - Maybe I am misunderstanding, but its not integrated authentication, it's just having the ability to use the existing user credentials for authentication to the sql server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you'll be able to log in to a windows domain account in this way. You need to set up a user in sql directly for this manner of passing credentials.

Comment: It seems that this is the only practical way to go for now.